# Using word boundary in regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a certain phrase using regexp, with words boundaries, but it's not working as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (preg_match("~\b(and you[?])\b~", " and you? ")) { echo "success"; }
```

**Does not echo "success".**

However with the word boundary excluded:

```
if (preg_match("~(and you[?])~", " and you? ")) { echo "success"; }
```

**It echos "success" for some reason.**

Comment: You used `\b` after `[?]`, which means after `?` there must be a word char. Maybe you need `"~\b(and you[?])~"` or `"~\b(and you[?])(?!\w)~"`?

Comment: It doesn't match because the word boundary after `you` is before `?` and there's no word (and therefore no word boundary) after that.

Comment: @frosty, please check the answers and my comment. It is not really clear what kind of a word boundary you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A word boundry does not match a question mark. So if you move the word boundry before the question mark, it will echo "success"

```
if (preg_match("~(\band you\b[?])~", " and you? ")) { echo "success"; }
```

Comment: The word boundary is superfluous between `you` and `?`.

Comment: not working, yours will match "and you?random_text"

Answer (score 0):

in your case it will not match as the "?" is not part of a word, therefore the last \b will not match, you can try:

```
if (preg_match("~(\band you[?])(?=\s|$)~", " and you? ")) { echo "success"; }
```

which is all instances of "and you?" followed by a space type character or end of string.